# How to use local R installation on HPC with qsub

Tags: r, bash, hpc, qsub

I work with a cluster where it is not possible to globally install a specific R version. Given that I built a specific version for R on folder:

```
<generic_path>/R/R-X.Y.Z
```

and I installed some packages locally on:

```
<generic_path/R/packages
```

how can I set, in a shell script (bash), the environment variables and aliases to run this specific R version, loading the packages from the local package directory?

Comment: @zx8754 If you want to add this to my answer I am transforming it to community wiki

Comment: Could have left as an answer, and get upvotes, it is encouraged to answer your own questions :), anyway updated your post, will delete my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
Using a shell script for HPC (in my case a qsub script), this is possible by running a shell script (e.g. in bash), which contains the following lines:

```
alias R="<path_to_R>/R/R-X.Y.Z/bin/R"
export R_LIBS="<path_to_R>/R/packages"
export PATH="<path_to_R>/R/R-X.Y.Z/bin:${PATH}"
```

The script (here I named it makeenv.sh) may be run inside the qsub script with:

```
source makeenv.sh
```

**Option 2:** Depending on your HPC system, you might have `module avail`, `module load` commands, if so then use:

*myBsubFile.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
# some #BSUB headers...
# ...    

module load /R/R-X.Y.Z
Rscript myRcode.R
```

Then load libraries in the R script as:

*myRcode.R*

```
library("data.table", lib.loc = "path/to/my/libs")
# some more R code...
```